# como cambiarle el nombre a una imagen al guardar en una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

quiero guardar una imagen en la base de datos pero al momento de guardar, si 2 tienen el mismo nombre una sustituye a la otra, como reviso que si existe una con ese nombre le cambie el nombre a la otra.

por el momento así tengo el código:

```
$Id_u = $_SESSION["Id"];
$clv_e = isset($_POST['clv_e']) ? $_POST['clv_e'] : null;
$seccion = isset($_POST['seccion']) ? $_POST['seccion'] : null;
$foto =  isset($_FILES['foto']['name']) ? $_FILES['foto']['name'] : null;
$ruta = isset($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] : 
null;
$destino="Fotos/".$foto;
$_SESSION['foto']= $foto;


If($clv_e!=""){ 
copy($ruta,$destino);   
$qry=mysql_query("insert into 
registros(clave_electoral,seccion,imagen,estado,Id_usuario) values 
('".$clv_e."','".$seccion."','".$destino."','Activo','".$Id_u."');"
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Le podés poner un `hash` al nombre de la imagen o usar `uniqid()` de php.

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió con uniqid().

Comment: Podes verificar si ya existe el archivo usando la funcion file_exists() de php

Answer (score 1):

Haz que el archivo temporal que creas tenga una función que cree un nombre nuevo en caso de que ya exista y así no duplicar el nombre. Yo cambiaría los Nombres de Destino del Copy() o Bien Haria Una Función que en el Destino Final de los Archivos Cree Nuevos Nombres para Los Archivos de manera que no se repitan.